# Model evaluation when training set has class labels but test set does not have class labels

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation

Training set and test set are separated in 2 files. The training set has class label and Random forest, svm, and KNN can fit. However, the test set does not have class labels. How do you evaluate the model? for example, confusion matrix, accuracy, and ROC require actual class for test set.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have time and wisdom to label your test set, you’ll have to ignore it and partition your training set into train/set, do all your training/analysis again. You can also report cross validation performance if you haven’t done any hyper parameter optimization with it.